# "Be" in this sentence is correct or wrong?

Tags: grammar

Please tell me why this sentence use be's original form.

> One of the players, Frank Mahan, suggested that the game ***be*** called Naismithball.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's totally correct. `Be` is used here in *subjunctive mood* (expressing a suggestion or demand) so it takes on the bare infinitive form, not present tense (hence no conjugation).